Disabling Auto-assign public IP in AWS EKS managed node groups with terraform-aws-eks registry
AWS recently has started charging for all the IPv4 addresses associated with your EC2 instances, NAT gateways or public-facing interfaces. If we sum up, it will be a significant  cost increase if you havenot thought about disabling auto assigning of IP address running in public subnets.
We run AWS EKS cluster with eks managed node groups created using terraform-aws-eks module. Also, we use eks-managed-node-group sub module to create multiple node groups that are spread across public and private subnets.
By default, the instances created in public instances are assigned an IPv4 public IP. Our K8S services are already behind Load balancers or ingress controllers, so there is no need to have the public IPs assigned to the worker nodes. Currently, the terraform module does not have any flag to specify disabling the auto assign of IP.
Is there a way we can achieve this flag to disable auto assign or any approach that has been developed to avoid unnecessary costs with IP addresses?

Since node group can be created from launch templates, specify that nodes of your app are created from LT that uses private subnet within used vpc.


If you have not specified any subnets in your launch template then
you can update the AutoScaling group's (Node Group) Network setting
to included subnets which do not have "Enable auto-assign public
IPv4 address" selected and remove the unwanted Subnets from the ASG
network settings. Then the Autoscaling group will deploy new set of
EC2 instances(EKS Nodes).
Or if you have specified the subnets in the launch template then
create a new version of the current template and include the Subnet
groups which do not have "Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address".
And later update the AutoScaling Group.

